# How can I get access to ViewController from MPNowPlayingInfoCenter

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, viewcontroller, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I'm working on an audio player and came across this situation:
I have a TrackDetailView that opens to play a track when I click on a TableView cell. Also I have implemented background playback and MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.
When I press Pause or Play button in MPNowPlayingInfoCenter, I want the button image to change on my TrackDetailView as well, but I just can't do it. I will be glad for any help.
Important note(!) TrackDetailView and MPNowPlayingInfoCenter are in different classes. When I put them in one class everything works without problems.
My code:

```
class TrackDetailView: UIView {
   var audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()
   ...
   @IBOutlet var playPauseButton: UIButton!
   ...
   //Loading with view
   func set() {
   setupMediaPlayerNotificationView()
   }
}

class AudioPlayer {
var trackDetailView: TrackDetailView?
func setupMediaPlayerNotificationView() {
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        
        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
            if self.player.rate == 0.0 {
                self.player.play()
                self.trackDetailView?.playPauseButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause"), for: .normal)
            }
            return .commandFailed
        }
        
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
            if self.player.rate == 1.0 {
                self.player.pause()
                self.trackDetailView?.playPauseButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "play"), for: .normal)
                return .success
            }
            return .commandFailed
        }
       ...
    }
}
```

I think I have a problem with an instance of the TrackDetailView class.

Comment: How does `var trackDetailView: TrackDetailView?` get set?

Comment: What do you have in mind?

Comment: I'm asking you how the variable gets initialized.  When you write `self.trackDetailView?.playPauseButton.setImage` you're saying it's OK to silently do nothing if it's nil...which might be what's happening.

Comment: @VyacheslavB like Philip says make sure `trackDetailView` isn't nil for this `trackDetailView?` to be effective and work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that for this instance

```
var audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()
```

you set

```
audioPlayer.trackDetailView = self
```

e.x here

```
func set() {
  audioPlayer.trackDetailView = self
  audioPlayer.setupMediaPlayerNotificationView()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It really works!
Can you explain this in more detail? Why was it needed?

Comment: shortly this `var trackDetailView: TrackDetailView?` is nil until you link it by assignment to an existing shown view otherwise nothing will work upon doing `trackDetailView?.......` so `audioPlayer.trackDetailView = self` comes to rescue